# Same value for each row in javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have created one table as in http://jsfiddle.net/TQXja/14/

My need is for a user is Busy is true once, then it should be true for all tasks of that user. But its always taking the 1 row value as I am mapping array as in line no 24, var list I am mapping array to get distinct user list.

```
var list = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.tasks(), function (item) {
    if (distinctUsers.indexOf("|" + item.members) == -1) 
        distinctUsers += "|" + item.members;
        return item;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please can you include all of your JavaScript and HTML in the post and elaborate further on what the problem is?

Comment: I have added the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure your code and have instead a User object that holds the value isBusy. Within this User object have an observableArray of Goals like so:

```
function User(name, goals, isBusy, userPresence) {
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.goals = ko.observableArray(goals);
    self.userPresence = userPresence;
}

function Goal(id, isPublic, note) {
    var self = this;

    self.goalId = ko.observable(id);
    self.isPublic = ko.observable(isPublic);
    self.note = ko.observable(note);
}
```